ubuntu studio 24.04.1 alongside kubuntu 24.04 on separate ssd disks
I have a laptop with 2 separate ssd disks (nvme ssd type), with already kubuntu 24.04 installed on the first nvme. Is it possible to install ubuntu studio 24.04.1 on the 2nd nvme disk, so that it is an independant installation (based on dual boot with grub) and that a installation on the 1st nvme with ubuntu 24.04 does not influences the installation on the 2nd nvme with ubuntu studio 24.04.1 and visa versa?
I need this way of installation because I can not reproduce de configuration on my current Kubuntu 24.04 installation of pipewire, jack, my audio interface and notation program. In that situation my midi does not work. Because I have disk space enough I want to do to separate installations?

If the installer doesn't provide exactly what you want, use the Manual Partitioning option to tell the installer exactly what you want.  You appear to be just asking how to create a dual boot system, without any specific problem defined (Ubuntu Studio uses the ubuntu-desktop-installer where as Kubuntu uses calamares, so how the installers look differs, but how they work is essentially the same; each with slight pros and cons)

My question is about independence of the 2 installations. It is not clear for me, when I do the dual boot installation, if the first installation can damage the second installation or the other way around, when I update my software on the first or second installation, because both installlatiin can seachothers partitions.

Both OSes are independent, UNLESS you specifically have them share a partition.  My system is a dual boot; I have Ubuntu plucky or the development release, and a LTS release which is currently noble or 24.04 LTS; the only shared bit between them I setup, ie. I have a /lts/ directory which lets me access the LTS file-system whilst using my current plucky, and the swapfile for current system is actually located on that partition (because I set it up that way; the default install has them all separated; I just have more on this development system when compared to lts)

FYI:  If I boot into my LTS; there is no /lts/ directory; to see this partition I access it via /next/ which is the name I chose... but that doesn't auto-mount as I see no benefit in that... ie. the setup I have is because I chose it & set it up as I wanted, the default is two independent systems (or another box I have have four OSes setup in dual boot all independent).  If unsure, use the manual partitioning scheme & you tell the installer what to do.

This question is similar to: How do I install Ubuntu on a separate SSD?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: How do I install Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
